# Open another existing panel when user click button

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jtabbedpane

I have created a java application which has a JTabbedPane that contains three JPanels. In my first panel I have a button. When the user clicks the button, it should open/show the second panel. Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

Comment: So when they click the button, you want the second tab to be selected? Is that right?

Comment: @dann.dev Yes, when he clicked it it should show the second tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the method [setSelectedIndex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29)

```
myTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(1);
```

Comment: Yes I did. You know, I have to wait 5minutes before accepting the answer. Anyways Thanks man.